# HTTP status code for successful login

Tags: authentication, http

I have a web application for testing. 
It has a login page.

For unsuccessful login attempts, the developers have made a custom error page so that the response from the web application shows 200 OK, but not signed in. 
This is ok.

Now the problem is when a successful login happens, they are redirecting the user with a 302 redirect to the dashboard.

Is this normal? I believe a 2xx status code is the best for a successful login.

Is my assumption right?

Is there any security issue related to this?

Answer (score 4):

Redirection the user after a successful login is common in the most webapps. 
For instance when the user try to access the dashboard directly within its url, the system keeps the requested url and brings the user to the login page, after user signed in he is redirected to the dashboard not the homepage or something.

Comment: Okey. I didnt thought about that.

Comment: Use [303](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) as redirection code.

Comment: Google discussions of the PRG pattern first. There are a lots of pros of cons.